# Node-MSSQL query transactions

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, coffeescript

I am having trouble successfully completing a transaction to my database using the node MsSQL library, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql.  Everything seems to be executing, however, I am receiving no data to my DB.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
    # Create connection
config =
    user: ''
    password: ''
    server: ''
    database: ''

connection = new sql.Connection(config)

# Send to table
sendData = (a, b, dsHost, dsUsername, dsSessionname, dsMode, dsRemotelocation, dsSessionactivity, dsActivityduration) ->
    transaction = new sql.Transaction(connection)
    transaction.begin (err) ->
        if err
            console.log err
        else
            request = new sql.Request(transaction)
            request.query "INSERT INTO dbo.sessionManager SET host=?, username=?, sessionname=?, mode=?, remotelocation=?, sessionactivity=?, activityduration=?", [dsHost, dsUsername, dsSessionname, dsMode, dsRemotelocation, dsSessionactivity, dsActivityduration], (err, recordset) ->
                transaction.commit (err, recordset) ->
                    if err
                        throw err
```

sendData() could be invoked once or a thousand times depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request = new sql.Request(transaction)
request.query "INSERT INTO dbo.sessionManager SET host=?, ...], (err, recordset) ->
   // I think that your query is incorrect, e.g. by db constraints.
   // So you need check err here.
   transaction.commit (err, recordset) ->
       if err
          throw err
```